# vuejs2 Import not when name is changed from HelloWorld

Tags: import, vuejs2

I'm currently new to vue.js2 im wondering why im having problems with this import

```
<template>
 <div class="home">
 <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
 <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import LogIn from '@/components/LogIn.vue';

export default {
 name: 'loginScreen',
 components: {
  LogIn
 }
}
</script>
```

if i change the name "LogIn" to "HelloWorld" and then use that import in the components instead of LogIn it works fine, but as it is with this specific code, it does not work.

hope my question is specific enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the name like that, in order to use the `LogIn` component, you have 2 ways:

```html
<log-in msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"></log-in>
```

or

```html
 <LogIn msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"></LogIn>
```

---

This is a small demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/8nz2k508w8

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>`

to

`<LogIn msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>`

in your template.

You forgot to change the name of the component in the template.